# insufficient sql database permissions for user impersonationlevel config database

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, error, log

What do user try go do that the following error is generated in the wfe server log? I looked at the ULS log for dsmith01 and did not find anything. Please suggest.

```
Insufficient SQL database permissions for user 'Name: xxx\dsmith01 SID: S-1-5-21-3736358454-1868704084-1822373674-51997 ImpersonationLevel: Impersonation' in database 'SharePoint_Config' on SQL Server instance 'xxxx\SHAREPOINT'. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'proc_GetTimerRunningJobs', database 'SharePoint_Config', schema 'dbo'.
```

Comment: I would like to advise you to don't copy the error and paste it directly with any information from your environment like domainname\username and SQL server instance name, just blend that data as xxxxx :)

Answer (score 0):

we have seen this issue in our environment and reason is unknown. we were getting the error for "" procedure and i was confused why a user trying to hit the config db directly.

But for some reason permission messed up on the couple of stored procedure which 
cause impersonation break and in event log we are seeing the user name.

To fix this issue, please follow below steps.

1. Expand your SharePoint Configuration database 'SharePoint_Config'
   and navigate to ‘proc_GetTimerRunningJobs’ under Programmability
   ->Stored Procedures
2. Right-click proc_GetTimerRunningJobs and choose Properties
3. Click on Permission on the left launch
4. Select the Search button and browse for
   ‘WSS_Content_Application_Pools’
5. Provide ‘Execute’ permissions for ‘WSS_Content_Application_Pools’
6. Click OK

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a0d08e98-1fd6-42cf-b738-6ba3df082210/search-account-got-insufficient-sql-database-permissions-for-user-execute-permission-was-denied?forum=sharepointadmin

Answer (score 0):

We found the similar error today on Search. 'proc_MSS_GetQueryParameterSpecification

'http://tempuri.org/IQueryRuleOperations/GetQueryParameterSpecification' MessageId:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'proc_MSS_GetQueryParameterSpecification', database xxx_Intranet_Search_Service_DB', schema 'dbo'.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

We give permission to search account and it fix our issue.